# android phonegap audio player music get stop after 10-15 use

Tags: android, cordova

i have created an phonegap app in android in which audio player is call on every click event.
after 10-15 use(audio player event called 10-15 times) audio player get stop entirely, app become soundless.

same app run successfully on iphone without such weird issue

i am calling playAudio('music path') on every click event

```
function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position/1000) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not working in lower android version 2.2 working fine on higher version as this stuff depend on java script engine supported by various devices